# Golang web app automatically build and run

Tags: go

I'm currently developing a simple web application.

But I find it tedious to rebuild my app whenever I update my source files.

Is there any way to automatically build and run my web app whenever i update my source files?

Comment: You may want to look into writing automated tests instead of manually debugging the app. Then, when making a change, you'll just have to rerun the tests, which is much less tedious.

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU, i'm not trying to debug, i'm looking for tool/package to automatically, build and rerun my web app whenever I update my source file.

Comment: my point is that with automated tests, you wouldn't need to build and rerun the app all the time. You'd just need to rerun the tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very handy tool called [pilu/fresh](https://github.com/pilu/fresh) you might wanna check it out. We are personally using it on our project to automatically rebuild our code.

It's a very nice tool because it allows you to customize the file types to watch, and ignore files inside specified directories.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: There are several tools like this. https://github.com/tockins/realize is another.